# Derivative of $\frac{\sin \coth x}{\csc \sqrt{e^{\log x}}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Derivative Problem:

Hello, Ciao tutti, Buenos dias!
I am trying find derivative with respect to  x of function:
$$
G(x)=\frac{\sin \coth x}{\csc \sqrt{e^{\log x}}}.
$$
Derivativative rule for general functions depending on x:
$$
\left(\frac{\xi}{\zeta}\right)'=\frac{\xi' \zeta -\xi \zeta'}{\zeta^2}
$$
I have done:
$$
\frac{dG(x)}{dx}=-\frac{\cos \coth x \, \text{csch}^2 x\csc \sqrt{e^{\log x}}-\sin \coth x \cdot?}{\csc^2 e^{\log x}}
$$
How do we derivativate this expression w.r.t $\csc \sqrt{e^{\log x}}$?  Thank you!!!
Thank you for helping, Grazie mille, Gracias!

Comment: $\frac{d(csc(\sqrt{e^{logx})}}{dx}=\frac{d(csc(\sqrt{x)}}{dx}= -\frac{csc(\sqrt x)cot(\sqrt x)}{2\sqrt x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the product rule:

$$(f\cdot g)' = f'\cdot g + f\cdot g'$$

So:

$$G(x)=\sin \coth x\frac{1}{\csc \sqrt{e^{\log x}}} \implies \\ G'(x) = \color{Blue}{(\sin \coth x)'}\frac{1}{\csc \sqrt{e^{\log x}}} + \sin \coth  \color{Green}{(\frac{1}{\csc \sqrt{e^{\log x}}})'}$$

But:
$$\color{Blue}{(\sin \coth x)'} = \frac{d \color{Red}{\sin} \coth x}{d\coth x}\frac{d\coth x}{dx} = \color{Red}{\cos}(\coth x)\cdot(-\mbox{csch}^2)$$

and
$$ \begin{align}\color{Green}{(\frac{1}{\csc \sqrt{e^{\log x}}})'} &= \frac{d}{dx}(\csc \sqrt{e^{\log x}})^{-1} = \frac{d(\csc \sqrt{e^{\log x}})^{-1}}{d\csc \sqrt{e^{\log x}}}\frac{d\csc \sqrt{e^{\log x}}}{d\sqrt{e^{log x}}}\frac{d\sqrt{e^{log x}}}{de^{\log x}}\frac{de^{log x}}{dx}\\&=-(\csc \sqrt{e^{\log x}})^{-2}\cdot-\cot(\sqrt{e^{\log x}})\csc(\sqrt{e^{log x}})\cdot\frac{1}{2}[e^{\log x}]^{-1/2}\cdot 1 \\&=\frac{\cos(\sqrt{x})}{2x\sqrt{x}}\end{align}$$

Back in the third equation:

$$G'(x) = \cos(\coth x)\cdot(-\mbox{csch}^2)\frac{1}{\csc \sqrt{e^{\log x}}} + \sin \coth\frac{\cos(\sqrt{x})}{2x\sqrt{x}}$$

Answer (score 2):

The way I will do it is as follows:

$$\coth x=\dfrac{1+e^{-2x}}{1-e^{-2x}}.$$

$$\csc x=\dfrac{1}{\sin x}.$$

Now you function $G(\cdot)$ is like this:

$$G(x)=\sin f(x)\cdot \sin g(x),$$
where $f(x)=\coth x$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{e^{\log x}}$.

Now use the chain rule. $$G'(x)=\left(\sin f(x)\right)'\cdot\sin g(x)+\left(\sin g(x)\right)'\cdot\sin f(x).$$

$$\left(\sin f(x)\right)'=f'(x)\cos f(x),$$
and
$$\left(\sin f(x)\right)'=g'(x)\cos g(x),$$

Now get $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$.

$$f'(x)=\dfrac{-1}{\sinh^2x}.$$

And to get the $g'(x)$, make sure you know that:

$$\left(\sqrt{h(x)}\right)'=\dfrac{-h'(x)}{2\sqrt{h(x)}}.$$

Your $h(x)=e^{\log x}=x$ if the $\log(\cdot)$ is the natural one (else, you will get some constant).

You are done. I hope it helps (but first I hope I did not make mistakes).